# Haskell's Either v. Error

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#error) presents `Error`:

```
instance (Error e) => Monad (Either e) where  
    return x = Right x   
    Right x >>= f = f x  
    Left err >>= f = Left err  
    fail msg = Left (strMsg msg)
```

[Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-Either.html) presents `Either`:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

If I understand correctly, then `Error` is a Monad with `Either` as it's `a` type.  Also, it looks like there's a `fail` to handle exceptions.

But, I also see that there's a `Control.Monad.Either` too - http://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.53.4/docs/Control-Monad-Either.html.

Why would `Control.Monad.Error` be chosen over `Control.Monad.Either`, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `Error` is not a monad. `Either e` is a monad, and `Error e` *was* a typeclass prerequisite for the `Monad` instance for `Either e` to exist. Basically `Error e` means that `e` is a type which you can convert error messages into with `strMsg`, which *was* used for `Either e`'s `fail` method.

However, people found this requirement to have an `Error e` instance just to be able to use `Either e` as a monad annoying, so after LYAH was written it was actually *removed*. Now the instance is just

```
instance Monad (Either e) where
    return = Right
    Left  l >>= _ = Left l
    Right r >>= k = k r
```

and `fail` instead uses the default from the `Monad` class definition:

```
fail s      = error s
```

However, the `Error e` requirement is still (as of newest Haskell Platform at least) required for the monads and transformers defined in `Control.Monad.Error`, while `Control.Monad.Either` leaves out that requirement.